# Phone gap application close if i move to other folder

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am making a application in phone gap cord-ova 2.7.0 Android OS specific with camera feature and social sharing feature. In my application when I choose image selection feature. Then it moves me to gallery folder and when I come back after selecting picture by pressing back button, my application stops. I am totally confused.

Things I already tried:

1. There is no mistake in camera event feature because if I select a picture fast and come back to application. Then it does not stops but if i waste 5 sec to select a picture my application state get lost.
2. I have tried pause and resume event but its not helping in that problem.
3. I have checked all values .no null value found!

Important things to notice:

Same issue happens with social feature if I go on Twitter to share my message and come back to the application stops.

Comment: R u testing on emulator or on device ???

Comment: i am testing it on my cellphones.i have tried it on three phones but same problem occurs.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In your device Go to settings --> Developer options -->In apps tab check "Don't keep activities".
If it is checked uncheck it and try.

Comment: ok i check this but tell me one thing.if a my application users will use my application without tab check then how can i stop it to crash?

Comment: no it shows  alert message that application stopped unexpectedly.it not a error or exception.its just application is losing its state and i am not getting solution to maintain this.

Comment: Sorry sir but you are not getting my problem.i do not want to stop application when it goes in background,instead i want its state active even if any other application opens and we come back.so please help in this context.

Comment: can you please solve it .i have tried so much but its not solved yet

Comment: yes ,i have tried pause and resume events,then i handled with try and catch also but nothing happens,i tried your solution but its not working .i added a log service to check but no error cached in log also.

Comment: android version of ur device ?

Comment: 4.2 version,i am using samsung and karbon phones to test it.

Comment: ,ok thanks  for replying so fast.now i find any other way ,thanks

Comment: Share your answer over here so that it can help other :-)

Comment: No I said that I'l find any other way till nw I was using ur solution.